# What could be the reason for duplicating an existing question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/38870/how-can-we-manage-our-17-year-old-son-taking-back-an-item-we-have-confiscated-e) was asked today on Parenting. It immediately rang a bell when I read it so I went for search which returned a result very quickly: [this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/32417/how-can-we-manage-our-adult-son-taking-back-an-item-we-confiscated-without-our).

As you can see, except for very minimal text changes, this is the exact same question asked with a 2 years interval though. The OP of the second question is a new user and asked 2 questions in the past 24 hours. I'm still not sure whether their first question was a legitimate one but didn't manage to find a duplicate so let's assume it was.

For what reasons would one create a questions which is an exact duplicate of another on purpose? (I can't believe this is a coincidence, the texts are too similar.)

Comment: The user may have thought that the question was gone and unanswered if it rolled off the front page of the stack, and asked it again because it wasn't answered. Flag or VTC (whichever you have sufficient rep on the stack for) one of them as a possible duplicate of the other.

Comment: It might not hurt to explain why in the comments, either.

Comment: These questions are almost 2 years away from on to another. Also, the slight changes (First question: "My husband and I...", second one: "My wife and I...", first question "3 years ago", second question "2 years ago") indicate this is not the same person having lost sight of their initial question. This is especially obvious as I had no trouble finding the first with the simple word "confiscated", it's the first search result! I did flag it, I'm just trying to understand why someone would do that as there's nothing to win.

Comment: Only the user who posted the question can tell you, everyone else can only speculate. The account of the user asking the first question was deleted, so it may be the same person asking the same question again.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin the oldest question has plenty of answers, so it going unanswered wouldn't be an argument that flies well with me. It might be they started a new account, and found that their previous post was so successful they duplicated it in hopes to achieve similar reputation gain on their new account.

Comment: @LaurentS. - Point taken; I'll admit that I didn't check the questions; I just assumed based on my own experience with situations that would be described similarly to your question here. Given that, I'd flag/VTC the new one as dupe of the older one.

Comment: @AnneDaunted I actually hesitated to ask this question because indeed there's a lot of speculations implied. That said, I wondered if this was a known pattern or behaviour and what could be the consequences (like for example quickly gain reputation to somehow being able to harass another user, etc...). That's the first time I notice that in years of using SE sites, but maybe are there other occurences I didn't notice because of the very fine moderating system.

Comment: Are you asking about the specific example? About how it could be possible that certain duplicate exist? Or the reasons for intentionally creating duplicates?

Comment: I'm talking generally but about such posts that are an almost exact copy of the original. It's actually the first time I spot one, not sure if this is a common occurence though, so I was wondering why would anyone (or many people) want to waste time copying a question?

Answer (score 8):

There are some reasons I can think of. I'm *not* suggesting that they apply to this particular instance, I'm just listing a few things I've seen over the years here.

- Some spammers start off by copying another question (from Stack Exchange, or another website like Quora, Reddit, or a support forum), in order to appear to be a normal user. Only their first post gets reviewed (I'm not actually sure they know this), and when they write a second post (containing the spam) they hope to appear less suspicious. Sometimes, they use a thesaurus on the original text, leading to hilarious results; more sophisticated spammers use a text in a foreign language, feed it through Google Translate, polish it a bit and then post it.
- Some users assume Stack Exchange works like a forum, where it's often 'not done' to revive an old thread. They might repost a question hoping to receive new answers. (A correct way of getting more attention to an old would be to post a bounty, but you need some reputation to do that.) The old question might be their own (but posted under an account which is no longer available to them) or someone else's.
- Users may duplicate content simply hoping to gather some quick reputation. Especially on a site like Stack Overflow, nobody may notice that you're reposting something.
- It's plausible that a user sees a question on one Stack Exchange site, but wants to know what users on another Stack Exchange think of the question, and decides to post it there.

Ultimately, only the user him/herself is able to tell you why they did it, and *if* it was done with malicious intents, you're not likely to get a truthful answer. But I often like to apply [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor):

> Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity.

No matter what the motive, copying a post like this is only allowed if it's [properly referenced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and depending on where the original content is hosted, it might not even be allowed at all. Stack Exchange content is licensed under [CC BY-SA <s>3.0</s> 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) which means you may copy it *if* you provide proper attribution.

Comment: As I was discussing in the comments above, I actually wondered if there was a malicious intent or if it was just a stupid thing done with no reason. I agree with Hanlon's razor, but still on the Internet (and IRL also actually) I think it might be more careful to always wonder about the possible malicious intent.

Comment: Ideally, it shouldn't matter: you have the tools to deal with problematic content (flagging / voting to close); moderators have the tools to deal with problematic *users*.

Comment: You're right, I'm just of a curious nature :-) I upvoted your answer anyway as all the reasons you mention make sense and I only though about the "quick reputation growth" one...